# Pagination not working with WP_Query (creates links but no page)

Tags: wp-query, query

The following loop gets all posts within a relevant category. It does generate a pagination URL, but it does not take me there (it just redirects back to the homepage).

Would anyone know why?

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$category_cat_args =
    array(
    'category_name' => $current_category,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    '&paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $category_cat_args );
?>
<div class="category-page">
    <div class="col68-2r">
        <h1 class="post-title">
        <?php echo $current_category; ?> news</h1>
        <?php
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
        $wp_query->the_post();
        $images = get_field( 'gallery' );
        if ( $images ):
        ?>
        <div class="col33">
            <div class="img-ctnr">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <img src="<?php  echo $images[0]['url'];?>" alt="example-image">
                <?php bottom_note(); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        endif;
        endwhile;
        else: echo "There are no posts in this category";
        endif;
        ?>

        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php  echo get_next_posts_page_link();  ?>" class="btn-ar"> more articles</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); change to wp_pagenavi($wp_query);
```

I think that $wp_query is the variable that you define! That is the thing you will need to insert! Sometimes, you will need to pass $wp_query->max_num_pages depend on your custom query request

Comment: Thanks, but that receives an error: `CATCHABLE FATAL ERROR: OBJECT OF CLASS WP_QUERY COULD NOT BE CONVERTED TO STRING`. And using `wp_pagenavi($wp_query->max_num_pages);` still just redirects me to the homepage.